# Why does BeautifulSoup keep saying I need to update my browser?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the leaderboard table from the PGA Tour website into a dataframe using bs4.  I am new to HTML and a relative novice with Python.  When working through bs4 tutorials using sample websites (e.g. 'https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/') everything works just like the examples, but the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table_body = soup.find('table')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

gives me the error message:

> ['', 'It appears your browser may be outdated. For the best website experience, we recommend updating your browser.\xa0\n                            \n                                \n                                    learn more', '']

My default browser is Chrome and it was updated yesterday.  I copied my user-agent info from a website in a tutorial.

What do I need to change/update in order to access the tables on the website?

Comment: probably due to the "User-Agent" header, you shouldn't need to include that in your get request

Comment: That webpage uses Javascript to load the information to display to the user.  The core webpage itself displays the error you're seeing if the Javascript logic fails to run.  Beautifulsoup on it's own will be unable to pull down the information.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is loaded using javascript, using beautiful soup won't be possible as Anon commented.

You could get the data using selenium instead, which can handle javascript. The below snippet would collect the leaderboard table rows.

Basically what it does is that it:

- loads the page
- waits until the leaderboard table is visible on the page
- when table visible, get all row items using xpath

**However**: note that you need to use a chromedriver (or any other webdriver), and change the driver path in the snippet below. My path is as shown below due to using it in a maven project, so it depends on where you install the driver.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html"
driver_path = '/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/driver/chromedriver/chromedriver' #Path to your chromedriver used by selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "stroke-play-container")))
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"stroke-play-container\"]/div/div/div/table/tbody')
for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize bs4 can't handle java. Your solution worked in that it got me the data. I now have a whole new set of questions about getting it into a more usable format with headers, but I'll post a separate question.

Comment: @SQLSqirrel glad to hear it helped. Kindly upvote and accept answer :) thanks